# Java If -else statement not working as expected

Tags: java, if-statement

So I'm making a program on a pretty low level of Java-programming. 
This is what I'm having problems with:

```
//The String fillText is given a value earlier in the program
if ("".equals(txa1.getText()))
{
    txa1.setText(fillText);
    txa1.setVisible(true);
}
else if ("".equals(txa2.getText()))
{
    txa2.setText(fillText);
    txa2.setVisible(true);
}
else if ("".equals(txa3.getText()))
{
    txa3.setText(fillText);
    txa3.setVisible(true);
}
else if ("".equals(txa4.getText()))
{
    txa4.setText(fillText);
    txa4.setVisible(true);
}
else if ("".equals(txa5.getText()))
{
    txa5.setText(fillText);
    txa5.setVisible(true);
}
...
```

This code appears to ALWAYS fill all of the textareas (txaX) with fillText.
I was expecting it to only execute the first of the statements that returned true and then break out of the if-else-statement.

I tried to do it with a switch-case, but ended up failing since the String is changed during the run of the program.

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it in a loop or a listener of these textfields?

Comment: Looks like the problem lies somewhere else in your code, not here. Check if this code is executed more than once in your program (like in a loop or in different calls in some place).

Comment: can u explain clearly pls.....

Comment: It was in a loop, problem solved, thank you guys for your quick answers. This was the first time i ever posted here and GOD you guys are amazing! Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It  is in loop .Definetely that is causing the problem.With out loop it will go to only one block.It is not possible too execute without loop.When ever we are using if else only one block will execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
"".equals(txa1.getText())
```

I think above condition for each returns true.

`getText()` method is always returning empty string i.e "";

Answer (score 0):

You have to carefully examine your conditions, it'll basically execute the predecessors if the condition is false.
I suggest you think more on the logic of what you are trying to achieve..